# How to retrieve items from an array of arrays?

Tags: zsh, array, parameter, brace-expansion, associative-array

Hello StackExchange pros!

I am working on a zsh project for macOS. I used typeset to create three associative arrays to hold values, and a fourth array to reference the individual arrays. Is it possible to iterate over the arrCollection to retrieve the key/value pairs from each of the member arrays? Note that the keys in the arrays below are not the same as my production script--they are simply key indices rather than the more descriptive keys you might find in an associative array.

I thought I could use parameter expansion like this:

```
for k in $(sort <<< "${(kvF)arrCollection}"); do
   echo "$arrCollection["${(kvF)k}"]"
done
```

I don't have it quite right though. Can anyone help?
Expected output will be a list of all items from all three arrays separated by a newline.

### Full script sample below. Usage: arrTest.sh showAll

```
#!/bin/zsh

key=$1

typeset -A arrOne arrTwo arrThree
typeset -A arrCollection

#Plan is to use an array of arrays so that a for loop can be used later to loop
#through each key/value pair looking for a value that matches some pattern in an if statement
#(if statement not included here). In the showAll case, how can I use parameter expansion to print all
#of the values in each array? The if statement will further constrict what is actually echoed based on its
#value.

arrOne[1]="First"
arrOne[2]="Second"
arrOne[3]="Third"
arrOne[4]="Fourth"

arrTwo[1]="Purple"
arrTwo[2]="Orange"
arrTwo[3]="Red"
arrTwo[4]="Green"
arrTwo[5]="Blue"

arrThree[1]="First"
arrThree[2]="Red"
arrThree[3]="Planet"
arrThree[4]="Sun"
arrThree[5]="Moon"
arrThree[6]="Star"

#Array of arrays
arrCollection[1]=arrOne
arrCollection[2]=arrTwo
arrCollection[3]=arrThree

#Expect a parameter
if [ -z "$key" ]
then
    echo "Please enter a parameter"
else
    case "$key" in
    showAll)
        for k in $(sort <<< "${(kvF)arrCollection}"); do
            #This is the part I am having trouble with
            echo "$arrCollection["${(kvF)k}"]"
        done
        exit 1
    ;;
    *)
        echo "Something goes here"
        exit 1
    ;;
    esac
fi
```

Comment: The keys of your associative arrays seem to be decimal integers and in sequence and starting from 1. Why not use plain arrays instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you're using associative arrays instead of plain arrays when your keys are sequential decimal numbers starting from one, but if I understand what you want correctly, you could do:

```
for key in "${(nok@)arrCollection}"; do
  print -r - "Assoc $key: $arrCollection[$key]"
  printf ' "%s" => "%s"\n' "${(@kvP)arrCollection[$key]}"
done
```

Which on your sample should give something like:

```
Assoc 1: arrOne
 "3" => "Third"
 "4" => "Fourth"
 "1" => "First"
 "2" => "Second"
Assoc 2: arrTwo
 "3" => "Red"
 "4" => "Green"
 "5" => "Blue"
 "1" => "Purple"
 "2" => "Orange"
Assoc 3: arrThree
 "3" => "Planet"
 "4" => "Sun"
 "5" => "Moon"
 "6" => "Star"
 "1" => "First"
 "2" => "Red"
```

Or to also sort members of each assoc numerically on keys:

```
for key in "${(nok@)arrCollection}"; do
  print -r - "Assoc $key: $arrCollection[$key]"
  for assoc_key in "${(@knoP)arrCollection[$key]}"; do
    printf ' "%s" => "%s"\n' "$assoc_key" "${${(P)arrCollection[$key]}[$assoc_key]}"
  done
done
```

Which would give:

```
Assoc 1: arrOne
 "1" => "First"
 "2" => "Second"
 "3" => "Third"
 "4" => "Fourth"
Assoc 2: arrTwo
 "1" => "Purple"
 "2" => "Orange"
 "3" => "Red"
 "4" => "Green"
 "5" => "Blue"
Assoc 3: arrThree
 "1" => "First"
 "2" => "Red"
 "3" => "Planet"
 "4" => "Sun"
 "5" => "Moon"
 "6" => "Star"
```

Keys above are sorted using the `o` (order) and `n` (numerical) *parameter expansion flags*. With those, elements are compared using locale collation order except for the parts that are made of sequences of decimal digits¹. Sequence of decimal digits are interpreted a decimal integer numbers and compared numerically.

That's similar to what the GNU implementation of `sort` does with the `-V`/`--version-sort` option.

So `foo2-3` would come before `foo10-3` and before `foo2-10`, for instance but that can't be used for numbers other than positive decimal integers (`-2` would also come before `-10` and `2.3` before `2.10`).

To sort using other arbitrary criteria, while there are convoluted ways to do it in a builtin fashion in zsh, it may be easier to resort to `sort` if you can guarantee the elements don't contain NL or NUL characters and are not empty.

For instance with GNU `sort`:

```
for key in ${(0)"$(print -rNC1 -- ${(k)arrCollection} | sort -zg)"}
```

To loop over the non-empty keys numerically, but this time supporting all sorts of number representations (including 0x20, 1e-1, infinity, -20, 0x3.fp5...).

Above that's using NUL delimited records to feed the  list to `sort` and split its output, so assumes keys don't contain NUL characters. To use NL/LF characters instead, remove the `-N`, `-z` and change `(0)` to `(f)`.

---

<sup>¹ and NUL characters which have to be handled separately as the standard comparison API chokes on it.</sup>

Comment: Phenomenal! Thank you for helping out. The arrays in my sample script here were simplified. In my master script the keys have string values like -1000 and -1100. I wanted to simplify until I understood the syntax.

Comment: Beware `${(no)keys}` above for numeric ordering would be more like GNU `sort -V`, it would sort `-2`  after `-1` as the numeric component of that sorting only considers the sequences of decimal digits in the strings to compare.

Comment: To help clarify that 'Beware ...' comment, when sorting, it's an ASCII sort, _NOT_ a NUMERIC sort. The ASCII codes for '-' compare equally, so it next checks the ASCII codes for '1' and '2', which '1' comes before '2', so ASCII '-1' comes before ASCII '-2'.

Comment: @C.M., not with both `n` and `o` it's a strcoll() + numeric sort in that `foo` comes before `FOZ` and `foo2` comes before `foo10`, but only the sequences of decimal digits are considered for the numeric component of that sorting. `-2` comes before `-10` just like `foo2` comes before `foo10`.  In any case, outside the  C/POSIX locale, that has little to do with the order of characters in the ASCII charset.

Comment: Thank you Stéphane..the sort tip was helpful as well. For some of the arrays I ended up sorting with -V and for others I used -nr due to the content in each. Result was content that users would think was natural looking.